# Comapare two sentences and get the most similar sentences in two columns using NLP(Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, nlp

Compare string1 and string2. If it is a match then the sentences should be in a row(separate columns)alongside side the price column. It is just sample data. Suggest a way in which it can be done.

| A header | string1 | Price | Another header | string2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SUPAGRIPS 20PK | 25 | NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES EYE MUP REM 125ML |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SUPAGRIPS 50PK | 55 | Nivea | Nivea Q10 Power Protecting Day Cream SPF3050ml |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 1 PRPL 40PK | 35 | Nivea | Nivea Lip Care Hydro Care 4.8g |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 5 BL 40PK | 65 | Piksters | Piksters Bamboo Inter Brush 8 Pack Size 5 Online Only |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 6 GRN 40PK | 15 | Piksters | Piksters Bamboo Inter Brush 8 Pack Size 00 Online Only |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS INTERDENTAL BRUSH SIZE 00 (40 PACK) | 75 | Piksters | Piksters Supa Grips 50 Pack |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS HYDRO PICK | 85 | Piksters | Piksters Supa Grips 20 Pack |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES 3IN1 Cleanser WIPES MINI PK | 95 |  |  |
| NIVEA | NIVEA VISAGE Cleanser WIPES REFR FACE25 | 105 |  |  |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES EYE MUP REM 125ML | 115 |  |  |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES SPF30+ SENS DAY Cream 50ML |  |  |  |

DESIRED OUTPUT

| A header | string1 | Price | Another header | string2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SUPAGRIPS 20PK | 25 | Piksters | Piksters Supa Grips 20 Pack |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SUPAGRIPS 50PK | 55 | Piksters | Piksters Supa Grips 50 Pack |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 1 PRPL 40PK | 35 |  | Not Found |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 5 BL 40PK | 65 | NA | Not Found |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS SIZE 6 GRN 40PK | 15 | NA | Not Found |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS INTERDENTAL BRUSH SIZE 00 (40 PACK) | 75 |  | Not Found |
| PIKSTERS | PIKSTERS HYDRO PICK | 85 | NA | Not Found |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES 3IN1 Cleanser WIPES MINI PK | 95 | NA | Not Found |
| NIVEA | NIVEA VISAGE Cleanser WIPES REFR FACE25 | 105 |  | Not Found |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES EYE MUP REM 125ML | 115 | Nivea | NIVEA D/ES EYE MUP REM 125ML |
| NIVEA | NIVEA D/ES SPF30+ SENS DAY Cream 50ML | NA | NA | Not Found |

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you start getting downvotes on this question :-) In particular, you'll probably get a comment saying that SO isn't a code-writing service, and you haven't given any evidence that you've tried anything yourself.

Comment: If you're just getting started with NLP, I would recommend using spaCy. Super super easy to learn there's tons of tutorials on their website as well as youtube